# Puedo acceder al método de una propiedad en una clausula from?

Tags: c#, linq

tengo una cláusula `From` que genera un objeto por cada registro recuperado de una base de datos:

```
List<Product> products = (from product in listaProductos
                        select new Product
                        {
                            id = product._codi,
                            name = product.name,
                            price = product.precio,
                        }).ToList();
```

La clase `Product` tiene una propiedad llamada `categories` de tipo `List<ProductCategoriLine>`, ¿como puedo asignarle un `ProductCategoriLine` al producto durante su construcción en la cláusula `from`?

Es decir como puedo hacer algo equivalentes a:

```
List<Product> products = (from product in listaProductos
                        select new Product
                        {
                            id = product._codi,
                            name = product.name,
                            price = product.precio,
                            categories.Add(new ProductCategoryLine { name = "NombreCategoria" })
                        }).ToList();
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias crear una instancia de lista `List<ProductCategoryLine>` en la propiedad, como ser:

```
var  products = (from product in listaProductos
                    select new Product
                    {
                        id = product._codi,
                        name = product.name,
                        price = product.precio,
                        categories = new List<ProductCategoryLine>()(
                               new ProductCategoryLine() { name = "NombreCategoria" })
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, gracias.
PD, no tengo demasiado claro si incumplo alguna norma al dar las gracias por una respuesta correcta :_